# What does "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157" mean for an airport?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, aeronautical-charts

I was looking up the airport in Gorham, New Hampshire (2G8) on SkyVector and noticed it had a line that said "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157". I know FAR 157 concerns what is needed to build, modify, or decommission a runway. What does this line mean in this context?

Comment: Shorthand for "someone screwed up"

Comment: @Burke, going to wave camp?

Answer (score 10):

The plain language interpretation of "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157" would seem to indicate that the FAA was not **notified**, as required by [14 CFR Part 157](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-I/part-157), that there was an alteration to  Gorham, New Hampshire (2G8) airport.

SkyVector shows other airports with the same remark - "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157," such as  [44T] - Hoskins Field, [KF69] Air Park-Dallas, etc.

Since the airports that have this phrase:"NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157," are listed in a database (such as SkyVector and Airnav.com) it would also appear that originally a construction notification, with details about the airport, was provided to the FAA.

**The pertinent regulation:**

PART 157—NOTICE OF CONSTRUCTION, ALTERATION, ACTIVATION, AND DEACTIVATION OF AIRPORTS, specifically [14 CFR Part 157.3](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-I/part-157) states the following:

> Each person who intends to do any of the following shall notify the Administrator in the manner prescribed in [§ 157.5](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-157.5):
>
> > (a) Construct or otherwise establish a new airport or activate an airport.
>
> > (b) Construct, realign, alter, or activate any runway or other aircraft landing or takeoff area of an airport.
>
> > (c) Deactivate, discontinue using, or abandon an airport or any landing or takeoff area of an airport for a period of one year or more.
>
> > (d) Construct, realign, alter, activate, deactivate, abandon, or discontinue using a taxiway associated with a landing or takeoff area on a public-use airport.
>
> > (e) Change the status of an airport from private use to public use or from public use to another status.
>
> > (f) Change any traffic pattern or traffic pattern altitude or direction.
>
> > (g) Change status from IFR to VFR or VFR to IFR.

FAR 157.5 states that notification to the FAA is to made using [FAA Form 7480-1, Notice for Construction, Alteration and Deactivation of Airports.](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/faa-form-7480-1-notice-for-construction-2020.pdf)

**(Example Form only - not to be used)**
**(Highlighting on form is mine)**
[image]

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the explanation. Just curious, is there any way of finding out what exactly the violation was? I imagine both changing your lighting system and destroying a runway are both FAR 157 violations, but very different implications if someone is planning a trip.

Comment: @Burke9077 my guess is that the airport made an alteration of one of the elements listed on the form 7480-1 and did not **notify** the FAA. I don't know how you might find out what exactly may have been altered. (It's a notification requirement.)

Answer (score 1):

> What does "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157" mean for an airport?

**In short**

It means the airfield was not surveyed by FAA (or wasn't resurveyed after a change).

In the US, a landing strip can be opened by anyone, e.g. on their private property, without facilities verification by FAA, but it can be used only within certain limits, e.g. not more than 10 operations per day.

Airfields intended for certain uses, e.g. carrier operations, or instrument flying, and permanent airfields need some verification from FAA, this verification is triggered by filling a request for FAR 157, or for a more stringent framework.

---

**Details**

A landing strip which has not been declared to FAA under FAR 157 has limitations set in [157.1 Applicability](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-I/part-157/section-157.1):

> This part does not apply to projects involving:

> An airport at which flight operations will be conducted under visual flight rules (VFR) and which is used or intended to be used for a period of less than 30
> consecutive days with no more than 10 operations per day.

> The intermittent use of a site that is not an established airport, which is used or intended to be used for less than one year and at which flight operations will be conducted only under VFR

There is no obligation to use FAR 157 if these conditions are met.

On the other hand upon reception of the declaration, FAA surveys the neighboring to ensure the airfield is safe to use, and the above limitations are removed.

After the airfield has been declared FAR 157 compliant, FAA will also regulate future changes in the neighboring, e.g. new constructions, or crane erection to maintain the safety.