# If I own land, can I create a private helicopter landing spot for my personal use?

Tags: faa-regulations, helipad

If I own land(in the U.S.), can I create a private helicopter landing spot for my personal use? Would I have to register with the FAA or some other government agency?

Comment: Related: [If I own land, can I create a private runway on my property for my own use?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1383)

Comment: Also related: [What does "NON-COMPLIANCE WITH FAR 157" mean for an airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/101574/3201)

Answer (score 2):

Helipads have the same issue as runways (as mentioned in the comment above:  [If I own land, can I create a private runway on my property for my own use?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/if-i-own-land-can-i-create-a-private-runway-on-my-property-for-my-own-use)  )

Generally, local regulations (State, County, City) are what can make it difficult.  As part of planning to create a huge Amazon complex in NYC, Bezos wanted to be able to land his helicopter there.  With enough $Billions at stake, he was able to get approval:

https://slate.com/business/2018/11/amazons-new-york-hq2-helipad-jeff-bezos.html

Although, that deal ultimately did not go ahead.

The other thing that can be an issue is insurance for a helicopter that might not allow off-field landings.

It would be much easier for example, if it were on your own farm, when you use a helicopter to spray crops.

Essentially, the FAA doesn't care, as long as it doesn't interfere with other airspace.  But, local regulations might.

Comment: "*Essentially, the FAA doesn't care, as long as it doesn't interfere with other airspace*", right, but the airfield [has limitations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/101592/3201).